# using if for past event

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

Which one is grammatically correct? Situation: I already bought coffee.

1) I told myself I'd buy coffee if I find my book.
2) I told myself I'd buy coffee if I found my book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consistency, all words should be in past-tense. "You told yourself that someday when you finally found your book, you would treat yourself to a cup of the best coffee ever!"

My favorite reference book is "Woe is I" by Patricia T. O'Conner, where you can find this addressed on pages 76-80.

Comment: You are more than welcome!